# R: build custom installer for windows

Tags: r

I am building a custom R installer, following the instruction in "R Installation and Administration" I've installed the latest Rtools212.exe and Inno Setup.

After successfully running `tar --no-same-owner -xf R-2.12.1.tar.gz`

I've then run `make all recommended` from `R_HOME\src\gnuwin32` and it runs ok until I get the following message:

```
building package 'base'

cannot create /tmp/R860644: directory nonexistent

mv: cannot stat '/tmp/R860644': No such file or directory

make[3]: ***[mkR] Error 1

make[2]: ***[all] Error 2

make[1]: ***[R] Error 1

make: ***[all] Error 2
```

After checking the instruction, I thought it was about the environment variable `TMPDIR` not being set properly. So I tried two options:

1. create `c:\tmp` folder
2. add `TMPDIR` to the windows environment variable and set the value as `c:\DDDD` (an existing folder). I then checked the value of `TMPDIR` in R console by typing `Sys.getenv("TMPDIR")`, and the change was confirmed.

To my surprise, however, I still got the same error. It looks like: 1. the `make` commander can not find the default `/tmp`, which is actually existing; 2. the change of `TMPDIR` has not been recognized in this occasion, the `make` commander still try to find the default directory, rather than the changed one.

I also searched online for this problem, and from what I can find, I have done what people had suggested, so now I am stuck.

Can anyone give me some suggestions? Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Shu

Answer (score 1):

well, I just found a solution for my question,
I typed in "set TMPDIR=c:/DDDD" in the command window, and this time no error has been presented.
But I still wonder why my initial tryouts did not work.